# JMeter CSVDataSet access Filename value in Post Processor

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Need to save and parse the path the user has chosen for the CSVDataSet file and write results to that location. We automate most tests from CLI so have the CSV in a property, but a user can run via GUI and change the dataset.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7BLe.png)

I've loaded the ctx engine, can traverse the tree, find the key for CSVDataSet but all values when gotten are default, not what's currently in the engine.

I believe I need to use the key to retrieve the subtree?
Another thought would be the namespace similar to 'sampler' or 'ctx' for the CSVDataSet so this would work?

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet; 
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
import java.lang.reflect.Field; 

StandardJMeterEngine engine = ctx.getEngine();
Field test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
test.setAccessible(true);

HashTree testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine);
HashTree testPlanRoot = testPlanTree.get(testPlanTree.list().get(0));
log.warn testPlanRoot.toString();

for(Object obj : testPlanRoot.list()) {
    if(obj instanceof CSVDataSet ) {
        log.warn("getFilename: " + obj.getFilename())
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2023-07-13 14:38:15,997 
WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree$ConvertToString{
org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet@a690984c {
}
org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup@a43b7122 {
    org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler@acd5391d {
    }
    org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet@a690984c {
    }
}
  org.apache.jmeter.gui.MainFrame[frame0,2993,16,1550x926,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,title=CSVDataset.jmx (D:\TestScripts\Americas\Test.for.CSVDataset.jmx) - Apache JMeter (5.6.2),resizable,maximized,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,7,30,1536x889,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true] {
  }
}
2023-07-13 14:38:15,998 WARN o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: getFilename: null
```

Many thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see how you really "traverse" the tree without calling [traverse() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html#traverse(org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTreeTraverser))

> Of special interest is the [traverse(HashTreeTraverser)](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTree.html#traverse(org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTreeTraverser)) method, which provides an expedient way to traverse any HashTree by implementing the HashTreeTraverser interface in order to perform some operation on the tree, or to extract information from the tree.

Suggested code change:

```
def engine = ctx.getEngine();
def test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test");
test.setAccessible(true);

def testPlanTree = test.get(engine);

def csvDataSetConfigSearch = new org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass<>(org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.class)
testPlanTree.traverse(csvDataSetConfigSearch)
def csvDataSetConfig = csvDataSetConfigSearch.getSearchResults().first()
log.info(csvDataSetConfig.getProperty('filename') as String)
```

Demo:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, I also tried the traverse, but had the same result as the obj. 
I didn't try the combination of getProperty and traverse... thanks